# Thermal contraction for cooling

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

I've calculated by separation of variables function of temperature $T(x,y,z,t)$ for a cooling cube.

I wanted to know how much the cube will contract in one dimension after 10 second of cooling, during while the temperature is dropping.

I know that linear thermal expansion coefficient is

$\Delta x = \alpha_{L}x_{0} \Delta T$

How to calculate it? The temperature function $T(x,y,z,t)$ should be averaged over $x,y,z$? Thank you for explanation.

Comment: Because of the non-uniform temperature distribution within the cube, thermal stresses will develop within the cube to change the strain distribution from that obtained with unconstrained contraction.

Comment: So $T(x,y,z,t)$ should be averaged over $x,y,z$?

Comment: It's not going to be anything like that.  Imagine a bar constrained between 2 vertical walls.  You heat or cool the bar, and, because it is constrained, it cannot change length.  Instead, you develop stress in the bar.  Something similar is going to happen with your heated cube, because it cools on the outside first.  After your entire cube has cooled down to a uniform temperature, your result will be correct.

Comment: @ChetMiller I knew that the initial temperature of the entire cube was $100°C$ and the cube during cooling was changing dimensions, so the temperature was changing with time.

Comment: Correct, but you can''t use the equation you are referring to to quantify the dimensional changes, because there are internal stresses that affect the strains, and the equation applies to an unstressed state.  Have you ever heard the term "thermal stresses?"  If not, please Google it and see what comes up.

Comment: @ChetMiller So what equation let me find solution for this case? The temperature will be the function of one variable i. e. $T(t)$ in the solution of that equation?

Comment: I thought you were saying that the temperature is a function of x, y, z, t.  If the temperature is a function only of time, its would be uniform spatially, and you could use your equation.  Otherwise, you would have to solve the so called stress-equilibrium equation (a partial differential equation in terms of the 6 components of the stress tensor) in conjunction with the 3D version of Hooke's law (relating the local stresses to the local strains and to the local temperature change) and with the strain-displacement equations (partial differential equations relating the local stains to the

Comment: local displacements).  Along with these, one would have to provide displacement boundary conditions.  It would be a pretty nasty problem that is usually solved by packaged finite element software.

Comment: How would look like solution with stress-equilibrium equation?

Comment: Describing how it would look for a cube would be difficult.  But, for a sphere, in which the stresses, strains, and temperatures would vary only radially (which would still preserve the basic essence of the behavior) would be quite a bit easier.  Do you have enough experience to approach this problem?

Comment: Yes, I'm experienced. I wanted to learn this method.

Comment: OK.  You need to use the form of Hooke's law involving the thermal expansion term.  The principal stresses are going to line up with the coordinate directions.  Everything is going to be a function only of radius in spherical coordinates.  The only non-zero displacement is going to be in the radial direction.